# write health check endpoints if the service has no HTTP server

Tags: go, backend, health-check

I want to write health check endpoints for 2 different services, but the problem is they have no HTTP server.

if I can write health check endpoints how can I proceed. or is it mandatory to have an HTTP server to work on health check endpoints with Golang.

Comment: simply add http server code and handle `/health` route, or make Your healthchecker to communicate by none http protocol.  seems like You've Kubernetes or something alike, so better simply have http server code (should be not more than ~10 lines of code)

Comment: as an example I've tcp server with internal protocol, but I want to provide readiness, liveness checks - so I add http code

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add an HTTP health check handler to your application with something like this. Then, in the service that's performing the health check, just make sure it knows which port to run the HTTP checks against.

```
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    // Start the health check endpoint and make sure not to block
    go func() {
        _ = http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.HandlerFunc(
            func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                _, _ = w.Write([]byte("ok"))
            },
        ))
    }()
    
    // Start my application code
}
```

Alternatively, if you need to expose your health check route at a separate path, you can do something like this.

```
http.HandleFunc("/health", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _, _ = w.Write([]byte("ok"))
})
_ = http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

**Updated**
If you want to check the health of a go-routine, you can do something like this.

```
package main

func main() {
    crashed := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        defer close(crashed)
    }()

    select {
    case <-crashed:
        // Do something now that the go-routine crashed
    }
}
```

Comment: if i do not want to add HTTP Server @clark?

Comment: It really depends, what are you using to perform the health checks? For example, Kubernetes does HTTP health checks. Some services like Consul can do TCP health checks so if your health checkers supports TCP you could just set up a TCP listener. It would be helpful to know what you're using, otherwise, we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: actually we are trying to write health check for a goroutine with pub-sub client in it, and we need to figure out how to check its status. Can you help @clark??

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to check the health of a go-routine rather than just keep the go-routine alive. Health checks are usually created by external services because they have no control over the service they're monitoring the health of. If you have control of the go-routine and it dies, then just restart it. I updated by answer with a simple explanation of how to be notified when a go-routine dies if you really want to do this. @dastagirshah

Answer (score 0):

It's not mandatory to have an HTTP server.

You can ping the IP address of your service server. For example I use [ping](https://github.com/go-ping/ping) repo:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/go-ping/ping"
)

func main() {
    t := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)
    for {
        select {
        case <-t.C:
            err := checkService("google", "216.239.38.120")
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("notif to email, error:", err.Error())
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Hour) // to not spam email
            }
        }
    }
}

func checkService(name string, ip string) error {
    p, err := ping.NewPinger(ip)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    p.Count = 3
    p.Timeout = 5 * time.Second
    err = p.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    stats := p.Statistics()
    if stats.PacketLoss == 100 {
        return fmt.Errorf("service %s down", name)
    }
    fmt.Printf("stats: %#v\n", stats)
    return nil
}
```